# Datastore issue with objectify - running localy

Tags: google-app-engine

Google app engine version 1.9.76

when running locally , it shows an error, any idea pls

Error:

```
c.l.m.c.ExceptionHandlerController       : Error ==Missing or insufficient permissions.
[INFO] com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions.
[INFO]  at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:128)
[INFO]  at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:113)
[INFO]  at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:181)
[INFO]  at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:180)
[INFO]  at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$1.call(DatastoreImpl.java:177)
```

My Entity is

```
@Entity(name = "CITY")
@Cache
@XmlRootElement(name = "city")
public class City implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @Index
   private Long id;

Already posted in
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/xM9rJKMv-Ns

Comment: Have you made sure that your default App Engine service account (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) has the editor role?